# How do I authenticate to Azure using a Service Principal and the Python SDK?

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory

I am currently attempting to authenticate to Azure using the [`azure-mgmt-support`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-support/azure.mgmt.support.microsoftsupport?view=azure-python) MicrosoftSupport client and am receiving the following error:

```
AdalError: Get Token request returned http error: 400 and server response: {"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'xxx' was not found in the directory 'management.core.windows.net'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
```

I have double checked and am definitely using the correct `client_id` and `tenant_id`. What am I missing here? My code below:

```
from azure.mgmt.support import MicrosoftSupport
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import ServicePrincipalCredentials 

sub_id = 'xxx'
sp_creds = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id='xxx', secret='xxx')

SupportClient = MicrosoftSupport(sp_creds, sub_id)
```

Answer (score 3):

After a short walk and another look at the documentation, and I spotted my error - I was missing the `tenant_id` from the `ServicePrincipalCredentials` object. It's not obvious [from the SDK specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/msrestazure/msrestazure.azure_active_directory.serviceprincipalcredentials?view=azure-python) or error message that this is what was missing as the only required variables are `client_id` and `secret`, however when I looked at [this example in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-authenticate?tabs=bash#authenticate-with-token-credentials) I realised it was missing (pasting code below for posterity, in case docs page changes).

```
import os
from azure.mgmt.resource import SubscriptionClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

# Retrieve the IDs and secret to use with ServicePrincipalCredentials
subscription_id = os.environ["AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"]
tenant_id = os.environ["AZURE_TENANT_ID"]
client_id = os.environ["AZURE_CLIENT_ID"]
client_secret = os.environ["AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"]

credential = ServicePrincipalCredentials(tenant=tenant_id, client_id=client_id, secret=client_secret)

subscription_client = SubscriptionClient(credential)

subscription = next(subscription_client.subscriptions.list())
print(subscription.subscription_id)
```